# Undefined method error, but my method is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run my app, I get an error that states: undefined local variable or method `signup' for #, but I'm not sure why this is happening. According to the code below, Signup is a new class that I've defined.

Thanks for your help!

Controller code:

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @signup = Signup.new
end

def create
    @signup = Signup.new(signup_params)
    if @signup.save
        signup.add_subscrip
    else
        redirect_to new_signup_path
    end
end

end
```

Model code:

```
class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i }
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

def add_subscrip
    connection = GoogleDrive.login(ENV['g_username'], ENV['g_password'])
    ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title(ENV['spreadsheet_title'])
    ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    row = 3 + ws.num_rows 
    ws[row, 1] = self.name
    ws[row, 2] = Time.new
    ws[row, 3] = self.email
    ws.save
end

end
```

Comment: Please give the stack trace of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create method

```
def create
  @signup = Signup.new(signup_params)
  if @signup.save
      signup.add_subscrip
  else
      redirect_to new_signup_path
  end
end
```

My sense is that

```
signup.add_subscrip
```

needs to be

```
@signup.add_subscrip
```